# How to plot this image in Matlab?

Tags: matlab

[image]

Just like the above picture.

In the beginning, I have a text file representing a 0-9 matrix, like this (not complete)
[image]

and a mat file named colors that contains the RGB value of this picture.
This mat file is a 10*1 cell array, and each entry has three values.
How can I plot this picture by using  the 2 files?

Here is what I have done:

```
clear;
load colors.mat;
fid_pic=fopen('pic.txt', 'r');
zerochar=double('0');
for ii=1:256
   data{ii,1}=fgetl(fid_pic);
end
```

After loading the matrix file, idk how to do with the colors and plot it.

Comment: Use `imshow`. You need to convert the color map to a numeric 10x3 array.

Comment: any more details? I can't relate my matrix to the color map

Comment: The numbers in your text file are an indexed image, the MAT-file contains the color map. Please see the `imshow` docs: https://www.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/imshow.html#d123e182196 — you’ll find an example in there showing how to display an indexed image with a color map.

Comment: Note also that you need to load the data as a matrix (not as a cell array), so you can use it with `imshow`. The color map should also be a 10×3 matrix; you may need to convert it with `cell2mat`